# Understanding a sentence 〜声が誰のものか

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

> それでも、俺はその繊細な**声が**誰の**もの**かすぐに気づく。

Does もの here refer to a voice?

If so, would there be any difference between the above and the following?

> それでも、俺はその繊細な声が誰の**声**かすぐに気づく。

Is it simply to avoid repetition? If so, would it not be also correct to omit the noun entirely and say:

> それでも、俺はその繊細な声が**誰の**かすぐに気づく。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「それでも、[俺]{おれ}はその[繊細]{せんさい}な[声]{こえ}が[誰]{だれ}の**もの**かすぐに[気]{き}づく。」
>
> "Does もの here refer to a voice?"

Yes, it does.

> If so, would there be any difference between the above and the following?
>
> 「それでも、俺はその繊細な**声**が誰の**声**かすぐに気づく。」

There is no difference in meaning, but as you stated, repeating the same word only a few syllables after using it once like in this sentence would be avoided at all cost in serious writing.  (I take your first sentence to be from a novel or something because it uses the ***historical present*** at the end in 「気づく」.)

In informal daily conversations, however, native speakers do not frown upon  repetitions like this at all in most cases.

> " would it not be also correct to omit the noun entirely and say:
>
> 「それでも、俺はその繊細な声が**誰の**かすぐに気づく。」"

This sentence is grammatical and even natural-sounding, but again, it would sound too conversational with 「誰のか」.

The best sentence for use in a novel is the original one.