# Why does this Light Novel title get translated to the past tense?

Tags: verbs

The title of the light novel is:
ひげを[剃]｛そ｝る。そして女子高生｛じょしこうせい｝を拾｛ひろ｝う。

The English translation is:
I shaved. Then I brought a high school girl home.

I get that not having the past tense in that title would sound weird in English, but does the original Japanese title imply the past tense? Or is the title originally supposed to be "I shave. Then I find a high school girl."?

Thank you

Comment: A very good, touching book BTW, despite the odd title.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie i wish the english translation had all the chapters though...there's chapters about sayu having a nightmare that the translator seemed to skip or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Japanese novels tend to use [historical present](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61679/5010) like this quite heavily. The tense [may be switched in almost every sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55546/5010). Unless this novel is about someone who *habitually* brings high school girls home, it's possible to translate this title as if it were in the past tense at the discretion of the translator.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even realize that we used the historical present in english too haha